# Finding a certain character in a string from database return

Tags: php

I have the following class. Which returns certain fields. I am interested in Reference. I want it to split up the data so that after the query is returned  reference contains an 'A' then return that, if it contains a B return that. seperately so i am able to put it in table show the amount of a's returned, b's returned etc. The data is listed by room.

```
<?php


class CHWIPProgress {

    var $conn;

    // Constructor, connect to the database
    public function __construct() {
        require_once "/var/www/reporting/settings.php";
        define("DAY", 86400);
        if(!$this->conn = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD)) die(mysql_error());
        if(!mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn)) die(mysql_error());
    }

    public function ListWIPOnLocation($location) {
    $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT
            `ProgressPoint`.`PPDescription` AS Description ,`Bundle`.`WorksOrder` AS WorksOrder, `Bundle`.`BundleNumber` AS Reference,`TWOrder`.`DueDate` AS DueDate , `Stock`.`Description` as Stock , `Stock`.`ProductGroup` as Group 
        FROM TWOrder,Bundle,ProgressPoint, Stock
                    WHERE `Bundle`.`CurrentProgressPoint`=`ProgressPoint`.`PPNumber`
        AND `TWOrder`.`Colour`=`Bundle`.`Colour`
        AND `TWOrder`.`Size`=`Bundle`.`Size`
                    AND `TWOrder`.`WorksOrderNumber`=`Bundle`.`WorksOrder`
                    AND `TWOrder`.`Product`=`Stock`.`ProductCode`
                    AND `ProgressPoint`.`PPDescription` = '" . $location . "'
        ORDER BY `TWOrder`.`DueDate` ASC";
        mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE_NAME, $this->conn);
        $result = mysql_query($sql, $this->conn);
                    $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
                    echo "Number of rows : $num_rows"; 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $return[] = $row;
        }       

        return $return;

    }


}
?>
```

Comment: It is difficult to determine what you are asking help for. More people would be willing to help if elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ListWIPOnLocation` function appears to return an array where each item corresponds to a row from the query. You can iterate this array and isolate the items using [PHP string functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) and perhaps add them other arrays. There is more than one way to arrange the data, here is one example:

```
$returned = array();
$returned["A"] = array();
$returned["B"] = array();
foreach($return as $row) {
    if (strpos($row["Reference"], "A") !== FALSE) { // note the !== operator
        $returned["A"][] = $row;
    }
    if (strpos($row["Reference"], "B") !== FALSE) { // note the !== operator
        $returned["B"][] = $row;
    }
}
var_dump($returned);
```

Alternately, You can use the MySQL `LIKE` operator in the `WHERE` clause to retrieve the rows where the reference column contains a specific character:

```
WHERE ... AND Reference = LIKE '%A%'
```

Comment: using arrays does not get any values back. unfortunately.

Comment: AND AS THE REFENCE NUMBERS CONTAIN UPTO 26 LETTERS THE QUERY IS NOT VERY EFFICIENT.

Comment: What possible values does `$row["Reference"]` contain?

Comment: I got it fixed. Seems I missed an quote mark. Many thanks for your help